# Скрыть выпадающий список в select

Tags: html, css

В выпадающем списке Select пункты Option пролезают через все слои. Как закрыть выпадающий список блочным элементом?

```css
#over{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #880000;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<form name="myform">
    <select name="myselect" id="myform">
        <option>Выпадающий список - открой меня</option>
        <option value="1">Вот пункт 1</option>
        <option value="2">Вот пункт 2</option>
        <option value="3">Вот пункт 3</option>
    </select>    
</form>
    
<div id="over"></div>
```

Comment: По моему это невозможно, легче будет переделать на псевдоселект на дивах. Элементы форм очень плохо настраиваются, особенно `select`.